# SIGSEGV __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<int>::construct<int, int const&> in Codeforces Round #660 Problem D

Tags: c++, vector, segmentation-fault, gdb

I have been working on a problem from CodeForces round #660 [Problem D](https://codeforces.com/contest/1388/problem/D)

My code is as follows::

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

vector<vector<int>> child; //Array of b[i](parent) vs i(child)
vector<long long int> a; //We will update it later, and will be our subtree
vector<int> b,found;


void DFS(int index_ptr ,int *answer){
    if(found[index_ptr] == 0){
        found[index_ptr] = 1;

        //Call childor
        for(int i=0;i<child[index_ptr].size();i++){
            DFS(child[index_ptr][i], answer);
        }

        //As we are traversing back just add the answer
        *answer += a[index_ptr];
        if(a[index_ptr] > 0){
            a[b[index_ptr]] += a[index_ptr];
        }
    }
    return;
}

int main()
{ 
    int n,i,answer;
    cin >> n;   
    a.clear();  
    a.resize(n);
    b.clear();
    b.resize(n);
    found.clear();
    found.resize(n);

    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        cin >> a[i];
        found[i] = 0;
    }

    vector<int> parent;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        cin >> b[i]; 
        if(b[i]==-1)
            parent.push_back(i);
    }

    child.clear();
    child.resize(n);
    for (i=0;i<n;i++){
        child[b[i]].push_back(i);
    } 
    
    for(i=0;i<parent.size();i++){
        DFS(i, &answer);
    }
    
    cout << answer << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

But it returns segmentation fault

After running `gdb` it shows the following results::

```
Breakpoint 3, main () at flintTreasure_V2.cpp:54
54          child[b[i]].push_back(i);
(gdb) c
Continuing.

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x000055555555692d in __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<int>::construct<int, int const&>
    (this=0x55555576e368, __p=0x4)
    at /usr/include/c++/7/ext/new_allocator.h:136
136     { ::new((void *)__p) _Up(std::forward<_Args>(__args)...); }
```

I did compile it with `-Wall` tag and it didn't show any warning that I should be concerned of

I never encounter this type of Segmentation fault before, I guess it has something to do with my vector allocation or usage

Comment: You are trying to push to vector a number that you dont have any control on it. in this line child[b[i]].push_back(i);

Comment: So, what's `b[i]`, and why? What's `n`, and why?

Comment: It is a graph problem, `b[i]` represent parent to element `i` ,  there aren't any cycle in it so maximum there can be `n-1` edges. This `child` 2D-vector represents the **edge list**. Array `b` is of size `n` having elments either `-1` denoting it is a **root node** else point to any **other node[0:n-1]**

Comment: I did found what is wrong in it, I was trying to add a child to `b[i] = -1`, that is where this error came( **Out of Bound in Vector**, accessing `-1th` location in vector `child`). Sorry to bother you guys. Thanks for the time:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a general answer: you are not doing any explicit allocations or deletions, so it is likely the problem stems from an out-of-bounds access to one of the vectors. If you use `v.at(i)` instead of `v[i]` to access the ith element of a vector v, an out-of-bounds access will throw an exception, rather than cause a segmentation fault (or worse).

More precisely to this code: you are accessing the vector within `child` at index `b[i]`, but earlier it appears `b[i]==-1` is a valid or expected input. My guess, without seeing the input data, is that you are attempting to push back a value on to the vector at `child[-1]`, which is an out of bounds access.

Comment: The second paragraph is the actual fault in this code. But could you still elaborate on what actually this `_gnu_cxx::new_allocator<int>` error means? I never encountered it before

Comment: From the line shown in gdb, the implementation of std::vector::push_back is attempting to construct an int 'in-place' at the address `__p`, using the so-called 'placement new'. But `__p` has value `0x4`, so it's essentially trying to write an int value at a random piece of memory that is outside the address space of the program. This is what is giving the segmentation fault. The value of `__p` is so crazy, because it is interpreting whatever is sitting at `child[-1]` as a valid `std::vector` object, which of course it isn't.